# Preload Audio Files / Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, audio, html5-audio

I am preloading all my assets before I start a JS-based application doing:

```
assets = [....]; // files
$.each(assets,function(){
    var r = /\.([^\.]+)$/;
    var ext = r.exec(this); //get file type
    if (ext[1] == 'png'){
        var tmp = new Image();
    } else if (ext[1] == 'mp3'){
        var tmp = new Audio();
    }

    tmp.src = this;
    tmp.onload = function(){
        var i = assets.indexOf(this);
        assets.splice(i,1);
        if (!assets.length){
            console.log('all loaded');
            app.build();
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine when I have just `png`s in my Array, yet when I add audio (mp3s) the DOM element gets created, yet it never fires an `onload` so the app never starts. I tried adding a `tmp.load()` already but it didn't make any difference - also I couldn't really find any comprehensive information on the web. Is this approach even possible? Does an `Audio()` even fire an appropriate event? Thanks!

Comment: is the `preload` attribute no good for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events), which says you could use e.g. `loadeddata`.

I'd like to address some other points:

- Characters inside a regexp character group don't need escaping.
- Why not use jQuery for creating the elements and binding the event handler?

I altered your code a little bit:

```
$.each(assets, function() {
    var r = /\.([^.]+)$/,
        ext = r.exec(this), //get file type
        tmp = ext[1] === 'png'
                ? $("<img>")
                : $("<audio>"),
        eventName = ext[1] === 'png'
                    ? 'load'
                    : 'loadeddata';

    tmp
      .on(eventName, function() {
          var i = assets.indexOf(this);
          assets.splice(i, 1);

          if (!assets.length){
              console.log('all loaded');
              app.build();
          }
      })
      .attr("src", this); // only set after adding the load callback
                          // to avoid a possible race condition
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the RegExp