# How to detect if a page has fully rendered using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using `$(document).ready(functioon(){alert("Loaded.")});` it pops up the alert box that says "Loaded." even **before** the page has fully loaded (in other words there're loading still going on like images).

Any thoughts?

Comment: ready() executes for the page is loaded, which means the pure html text. If you'd like to check if all images is loaded, you may need to write more codes on some image event handlers I guess

Comment: In case you really want to make sure all assets are loaded you'll have to listen for each one of them. You can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332167/preload-audio-files-event -  the code in the answer works pretty fine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    //everything is loaded
});
```

Comment: is there any pure javascript version of this ?

Comment: It's not always working for me. Scenario:
1. make a page with large amount of pictures (100) on page
2. add event $(window).on('load', function() { window.print(); } );
3. open this page (try many times)

Not always all pictures will be visible in print dialog. Looks like on 2nd and more calls browser takes it from the cache and 'load' event fires earlier than render.

Answer (score 5):

Try out .load() instead.

```
$(document).load(function () {
    alert('Loaded');
}
```

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. 
>   http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: The (window).load did the trick for me though. (document).load doesn't seem to fire when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript

```
   window.onload = function () { alert("loaded"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it here. 
https://github.com/codef0rmer/learn.jquery.com/blob/master/content/jquery-basics/document-ready.md