# How to be notified when all my page elements have been rendered with html5

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

Is there a way to catch any event that should be fired when all parts of a page has rendered?

I'm working in an iOS environment and there is a random delay on rendering step between iPad2, iPad3, and iPad Air 2. The thing is that this delay cause inconsistencies in my code and unfortunately visual bugs.

To be very accurate, I'm not talking about loading (I've already tried the onload method and it doesn't works) but rendering. When all the images and / or dom elements fully display on the screen.

These posts don't help me.

[How to detect if a page has fully rendered using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630904/how-to-detect-if-a-page-has-fully-rendered-using-jquery)

[Running javascript after page is fully rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611713/running-javascript-after-page-is-fully-rendered)

Comment: Does “rendering” include all scripts being executed? Because DOM content loading and images loading is the `load` event.

Comment: Rendering from dom elements (image, div, ...). Also there are some backgrounds set by css (background-image). In this case javascript don't generate any visual elements