# Proper onload for <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

I've been looking around and I'm starting to worry that this isn't possible. 
Is there any way to make a standard `<audio>` tag  with fallbacks...

```
<audio>
    <source src='song.ogg' type='audio/ogg'></source>
    <source src='song.mp3' type='audio/mp3'></source>
</audio>
```

...have an onload event. I've looked around and all I could find are some hacks that may or may not work (they don't for me on Chrome) and the `canplaythrough` event. 
The reason I want this is because I am making a presentation that has lots of audio clips to play at certain points. I don't want the presentation to start until all of the audio is loaded (otherwise things could get out of sync). I want the clips to be loaded 1 at a time so that I can create a sort of loading bar. I really don't want to resort to using Flash sound because this is supposed to demonstrate pure web technologies.
So basically I've got this one `loadAudio` function that cycles through the array of audio files to be loaded `audioQueue`. `loadAudio` is called once and then it calls itself until all the files are loaded.
Problem is I haven't found the correct event to trigger loading the next file.

```
loadAudio = function(index)
{
mer = audioQueue[index];
var ob = "<audio id='" + mer + "'><source src='resources/sounds/" + mer + ".ogg' type='audio/ogg'></source><source src='resources/sounds/" + mer + ".mp3' type='audio/mp3'></source></audio>";
$("#audios").append(ob);
$("#" + mer).get(0).addEventListener('A WORKING EVENT RIGHT HERE WOULD BE NICE', function() { alert("loaded"); 
     if (index + 1 < audioQueue) { loadAudio(index + 1); } }, false);
}
```

So. Any chance for a proper audio onload? I'm basically willing to do anything as long as it's still all HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Had the same problem a while ago, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332167/preload-audio-files-event just "strip" the images part.

Comment: @m90 Ahh that works perfectly. Could you turn that into an answer so I can set it as the correct one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preload Audio Files / Event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332167/preload-audio-files-event)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `loadeddata`-[MediaEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events). For example you can put all of your audio files in an Array and do something like:

```
var files = ['a.mp3', 'b.mp3'];

$.each(files, function() {
    $(new Audio())
        .on('loadeddata', function() {
            var i = files.indexOf(this);
            files.splice(i, 1);
            if (!files.length) {
                alert('Preloading done!');
            }
        })
        .attr('src', this);
});
```

**EDIT**: this would a little more modern approach as of 2016:

```
var files = ['a.mp3','b.mp3'];

Promise
    .all(files.map(function(file) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            var tmp = new Audio();
            tmp.src = file;
            tmp.addEventListener('loadeddata', resolve);
        });
    })).then(function() {
        alert('Preloading done!');
    });
```

Comment: Wonder if this is still valid. Getting this error ******* Uncaught TypeError: tmp.on is not a function

Comment: So here's what I had to do .. Not sure if this is 'the solution', but works for me ****************************************************************************************************************************
 $.each(files,function(){
  var tmp = new Audio();
  tmp.src = this; //this gets converted to a URL
  tmp.textContent = this;
  $(tmp).on('loadeddata',function(){
   var i = files.indexOf(this.textContent);
   files.splice(i,1);
   if (!files.length){
    console.log('Preloading done!');
   }
  });
 });

Comment: `Node.prototype.on = function(...args) {
 this.addEventListener(...args);
 return this;
};`

Answer (score 2):

I did a small PONG-game with WebGL and some audio-tags for the sounds. I borrowed the audio-implementation from Opera's Emberwind HTML5 implementation: https://github.com/operasoftware/Emberwind/blob/master/src/Audio.js

Their solution worked fine for me (Chrome, Opera and Firefox). Maybe it could be of interest to you? They have some code that will try to find a playable format from line 22 and below.

Comment: That would work, but it uses the canplaythrough event and a "spritesheet" of sounds which I want to avoid. It's a great resource though.