# How can i use js/jquery to handle an event when a audio source file is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, load

http://jsfiddle.net/kent93/AyEpR/

i want to hide() the loader gif , after the audio has loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using pure JS you can do that by using `canplaythrough` event:

```
myAudio.addEventListener("oncanplaythrough", function() { ... here hide gif ... }, false);
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#theMp3File').on('canplay canplaythrough', function(){
    $('.loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

> > You can use the loadeddata-MediaEvent.

**Example:**

```
var files = ['a.mp3','b.mp3'];

$.each(files,function(){
   var tmp = new Audio();
   tmp.src = this;
   tmp.on('loadeddata',function(){
   var i = files.indexOf(this);
      files.splice(i,1);
      if (!files.length){
         alert('Preloading done!');
      }
   });
});
```

Quote and code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9716433/339852).